# Prove that the function $f(x)=\cos x^2$ is not a periodic one .

Tags: functions, proof-explanation, periodic-functions

I was going through a chapter about functions from " Problems in Calculus of One Variable " by I.A Maron . There was an example given in the book :

> Prove that the function $f(x)=\cos x^2$ is not a periodic one .

The solution given in the book is as follows:

> Let us prove the contrary . Suppose the function has a period $T$ ; then the identity $\cos(x+T)^2\equiv\cos x^2$ is valid . By the condition of equality of cosines for a certain integer $k$ , we have , $x^2+2Tx+T^2\pm x^2\equiv 2\pi k .$ But this identity is impossible,  since k may attain only integral values , and the left member contains a linear or quadratic function of the continuous argument $x$.

However, I am not getting how are they concluding the identity "$x^2+2Tx+T^2\pm x^2\equiv 2\pi k $" is impossible? Now, $k$ attains integral values but $\pi$ is irrational. How to make the contradiction seem more obvious ? Or rather, how is it so much immediate?I am not quite getting it...There might be similar questions related to the same topic but I can't seem to find it either...

Comment: The equation must hold for all $x$. Take $x=0$ first and then $x=1$ to get a  contradiction.

Comment: Note that $k$ depends on $x$. If you plot the left-hand side with respect to $x$, you get a continuous linear or quadratic curve. Whereas if you plot $2\pi k(x)$ with respect to $x$, you get a piecewise constant curve. So the two sides cannot be equal for all $x$.

Comment: "you get a continuous linear or quadratic curve"  Well, not exactly as $\pm x^2$ can discontinuously hop from pos. to neg. in any arbitrary fashion.  It still can't be piecewise though.  I suppose if one wanted to one could do a delta epsilon proof that the difference between the left hand side for any $x$ and $x+\epsilon$ for an appropriately small $\epsilon$ is either miniscule (but not 0) or miniscully close to $|2x^2|$ which means for most values of $x$ (those where $|2x^2|$ is not very close to an integer multiple of $2\pi$) this is impossible.

Comment: @geetha290krm Well, if $x=0$ , then ,$T^2=2\pi k$ .If $x=1$, then, there are two cases , $2T+T^2=2\pi k$  and $2+2T+T^2=2\pi k$ .  Now, we have, $T^2=2\pi k$ , so, if , $2T+T^2=2\pi k$, then, $T=0$ , a contradiction.  If $2+2T+T^2=2\pi k$, then, $T=-1$, a contradiction. T should have been a positive integer.  Hence, $T$ does not exists. Is this valid? ...

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Careful that $k$ depends on $x$: it may not be the same $k$ for $x=0$ than for $x=1$…

Comment: @nejimban That maybe true... so what do you suggest?...

Comment: Although $k(0)$ may not equal $k(1)$, it still stands that $k(x)$ will be the same for *many* $x$. More precisely one can show that the $\pm$ sign and $k(x)$ remain identical in a non-empty interval. This is enough to conclude (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists $T>0$ such that $$\cos(x^2)=\cos\left({(x+T)}^2\right),\quad x\in\Bbb R.\tag{1}$$
Define $k:=\lfloor\frac{T^2}\pi\rfloor$, which means that $k\pi\le T^2<(k+1)\pi$. Then $$I:=\left(0,\sqrt{1+(k+1)\pi-T^2}-1\right)$$
is a non-empty interval of $[0,\sqrt\pi]$ such that $k\pi<{(x+T)}^2<(k+1)\pi$ for all $x\in I$.
Now, observe that all three numbers $x^2+k\pi$, ${(x+T)}^2$ and $(2k+1)\pi-{(x+T)}^2$ all belong to the interval $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$ (which has length $\pi$). Thus:

1. If $k$ is even, then $\cos(x^2+k\pi)=\cos(x^2)=\cos\left({(x+T)}^2\right)$
   by (1), implying $x^2+k\pi={(x+T)}^2$. Hence $k\pi=2x+T^2$ for all $x\in I$, which is absurd (you may differentiate this equality to get the contradiction $0=2$). *“A linear function cannot be constant on a non-empty interval.”*
2. If $k$ is odd, then $\cos\left((2k+1)\pi-{(x+T)}^2\right)=-{\cos\left({(x+T)}^2\right)}=\cos(x^2+k\pi)$ by (1), implying
   $(2k+1)\pi={(x+T)}^2+x^2+k\pi$ for all $x\in I$. Again, this is absurd (you get $0=2$ again by differentiating twice this equality). *“A quadratic function cannot be constant on a non-empty interval.”*

This proves that $T$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

Note $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$ and assume that $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Then $f(T)=f(0)=1$ so $\cos(T^2)=1$ and $\sin(T^2)=0$. Besides
$$f(x+T)=\cos(x^2+2xT+T^2)=\cos[(x^2+2xT)+T^2]=$$ $$=\cos(x^2+2xT)\cos(T^2)-\sin(x^2+2xT)\sin(T^2)=$$ so we have for all $x$ $$f(x+T)=\cos(x^2+2xT)=f(x)=\cos(x^2)$$ so
$$\cos(x^2+2xT)-\cos(x^2)=0$$ in other words, we have for all $x$ that $$-2\sin(x^2+xT)\sin(xT)=0$$ which is absurd because none of the three factors in the $LHS$ is null.We are done.